# Only getting 1 result from postgres tsvector

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3. I have built a dataset with a tsvector field called vector.

Then I execute a query against it

```
SELECT id, vector, relative_path, title
FROM site_server.indexed_url, plainto_tsquery('english','booking') query
WHERE vector @@ query;
```

Only 1 row is returned. When I look at the data there are at least 6 rows that would match. How do I get it to retrieve all matching records?

[Data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0cF1aWFSwM5YnR3UmRyU2FELWs)

Comment: give us sample data please, all six rows

Comment: @VaoTsun I have included a CSV file with all the data.

Comment: how did you generate your `vector` column?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I just inserted text directly into it. I guess that is not enough. I am using an ORM for the insert so it might be difficult to do much more.

Comment: you can add `strip(to_tsvector('...'))` if you want tsvector without positions on insert (+- what you have ATM) or better `to_tsvector('...')` to be sure you insert tsvector instead of text that looks alike

Answer (score 1):

Values in vector column in your data sample are not normalized. Which is ignored on `COPY`, as per [docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html)

> It is important to understand that the tsvector type itself does not
>   perform any word normalization; it assumes the words it is given are
>   normalized appropriately for the application

If you run:

```
SELECT id, vector, relative_path, title
FROM site_server.indexed_url
WHERE to_tsvector(vector) @@ plainto_tsquery('english','booking') query;
```

It will produce expected result I think.